# how to use dropIndex() on node-mongolian?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

Hello I'm trying to delete a specific input in mongo db... I am using the [mongolian](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian)
client, and I'm sorry I haven't managed to grasp the API yet...

this attempt is failing

```
if(req.body.post.del){
     posts.dropIndex({_id:req.body.post.del}, function(err){  //this query must be wrong
      if(err)
    res.render('blog_edit', {locals:{title:'Failure to delete from DB'}}); //this is what I get...
      else
        posts.find({}).toArray(function(err, arr){
      if(err) throw err

      res.render('blog_edit', {locals:{title:'Success!', posts: arr }});
    })
    })
  }
```

please provide some help...
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to do what I wanted by using `remove` instead of `dropIndex` , still for some reason indexing by `_id` was not possible so I used title:

```
posts.remove({title:req.body.post.del}, function(err){ //this will work
```

this will not work:

```
posts.remove({_id:req.body.post.del}, function(err){ //this will NOT work
```